# Create Gnome Clocks alarm using gsettings

Tags: gnome, gsettings

I am trying to create an alarm in [Gnome Clocks](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-clocks/-/tree/master?ref_type=heads) using the terminal. I am trying to use `gsettings`, but no alarms are created.

1. Create an alarm using the user interface
2. Inspect the value using `gsettings`

```bash
gsettings get org.gnome.clocks alarms
[{'name': <'test for so'>, 'id': <'01da159f5b290d7b8c2e885c65088901'>, 'active': <true>, 'hour': <13>, 'minute': <41>, 'days': <@ai []>, 'snooze_minutes': <10>, 'ring_minutes': <5>}]
```

1. Delete the alarm using the user interface
2. Verify the alarm was deleted using `gsettings`

```bash
gsettings get org.gnome.clocks alarms
@aa{sv} []
```

1. Try to create an alarm using `gsettings` with a new `id`

```bash
gsettings set org.gnome.clocks alarms "[{'name': <'test for so'>, 'id': <'4e52429bb11746d39dcbe566597c3c8a'>, 'active': <true>, 'hour': <13>, 'minute': <41>, 'days': <@ai []>, 'snooze_minutes': <10>, 'ring_minutes': <5>}]"
```

1. Verify value was persisted

```bash
gsettings get org.gnome.clocks alarms
[{'name': <'test for so'>, 'id': <'4e52429bb11746d39dcbe566597c3c8a'>, 'active': <true>, 'hour': <13>, 'minute': <41>, 'days': <@ai []>, 'snooze_minutes': <10>, 'ring_minutes': <5>}]
```

1. Expect alarm to exist in Gnome Clocks, but there are no alarms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not a solution to my problem using `gsettings` I was able to simulate an alarm using `notify-send` with `at`.

e.g. `at "now + 1 hour" <<< "notify-send foo bar"`